# Column Chart not displaying annotation values at all

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to display annotations on my chart.  However, the chart will not display the annotations in any form.

Please help

```
google.charts.load("current", {"packages":["bar"]});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ 
             ["", "SAS 115","SAS 100", "SAS 100"]
            ,["Y3",23,69,31]
            ,["Y4",33,77,23]
            ,["Y5",36,95,5]
            ,["Y6",46,92,8]
        ]);

        var options = {
            legend: {position: 'none'},
            chartArea: {left:50,top: 10,height: '100%',width: '100%'},
            annotations: {
                style: 'point',
                alwaysOutside: true,
                textStyle: {
                    color: 'black',
                    fontSize: 11,
                }
            },
        theme: 'material',
        colors: ['red','green', 'purple']
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById("Cat4"));
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
    }
```

Comment: annotations are not supported by __material__ charts --> `google.charts.*` -- can only use classic charts if you want to include annotations -- `google.visualization.*`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a `missing comma` in your code, specifically after the `alwaysOutside: true` line within the `annotations section`.

Comment: I have modified that as was the original. But, the problem still is the same

Comment: @DuncanBellinger-Brown can you provide console logs.